# Locate water shut off valve

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet

I'm trying to locate the water shut off valve for my home. I'm trying to shut-off the water to replace and outdoor faucet. I've attached 3 pics of possible locations for it. Can anyone identify it for me?
In case it matters I live in Hawaii. 
Notes:
In pic #1 I already attempted tightening and loosening the pressure regulator bolt. It doesn't stop the water.

[image: 1 Backyard Faucet 10 feet from meter Water pressure regulator]

In pic #2, I attempted turning the large bolt head on the bottom right (next to blue meter cap) of the pic with an 8-inch wrench. It wouldn't turn. I was hesitant to buy a bigger wrench and put more leverage into it until I got some advice... [image: water meter in street]

Pic #3 is just a photo of my front left outdoor faucet. I only included it because the home inspection report I dug up listed the water shut off valve as being in the front left of the house. However, this is the ONLY thing that is not photographed by the inspector in the report, so I suspect it was made up and he never actually found it. But maybe the black sewer cap in the bottom of the pick is something to do with it?
[image: Front left faucet]

Comment: Take the cap off the big black pipe in #3 it is possible a shut off valve is down in this pipe

Comment: If you go in a straight-ish line from the meter in pic 2 toward the house, is there anything obvious? It's common enough that shutoff valves get buried under a bit of dirt. And have you called your water district to see if it's free for them to come out and do a shutoff? (Benefit to that is that if they break the valve, it's on them; if you break the valve, well... you get the idea.)

Comment: Thank you for the the response! I'll try the black pipe next. I called the water company and left a message, but they are hard to get ahold of.  They charge, and charge high for everything in HI, so I doubt it'll be free, but that's my next option.

Comment: I opened the black pipe. There wasn't anything inside. It goes straight down about 3 feet, then curves out of site towards the house. Guess I'll wait on the water Company.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the city meter in picture 2 ; In TX the home owner is not supposed to operate the 90 degree cock type valve at the meter ( not that it hasn't happened). There is another valve between the meter and the house . My valve is inside a large plastic pipe which I found while gardening near the foundation ( buried in leaves).

Comment: I'll suggest that there SHOULD BE a customer-owned shutoff valve on the home-side of the meter.  That doesn't mean it's actually there.  But all of the components from the meter to the street belong to the utility and should not be disturbed.  If you don't have a shutoff or cannot locate it, you should be able to have the utility shut off your service while you install a shutoff valve, for a fee, of course.